# How to ensure all task are executed using asyncio.gather?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

When using `asyncio.gather`, all tasks are not executed when one of them raise exception:

```py
# coding: utf-8
import asyncio


async def foo(i):
    await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
    if i == 2:
        print("2: 1/0")
        1/0
    print(i)


async def main():
    futures = []
    for i in range(1000):
        futures.append(foo(i))
    await asyncio.gather(*futures)


asyncio.run(main())
```

```
0
1
2: 1/0
3
4
5
6
7
[...]
501
502
503
504
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 24, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/runners.py", line 43, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "<input>", line 21, in main
  File "<input>", line 9, in foo
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

How can I ensure all tasks are executed before get out of `asyncio.gather` ? I understand this cannot be the default behavior of `asyncio.gather` because if one of my tasks never finished, exceptions will never be raised. My question is more: How can I execute a pool of tasks gather and wait all finished/raise before continue ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to pay close attention to the [documentation for asyncio.gather](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather):

> If return_exceptions is False (default), the first raised exception
> is immediately propagated to the task that awaits on gather(). Other
> awaitables in the aws sequence won’t be cancelled and will continue
> to run.
>
> If return_exceptions is True, exceptions are treated the same as
> successful results, and aggregated in the result list.

From my reading, it looks like if you were to call `asyncio.gather` like this...

```
await asyncio.gather(*futures, return_exceptions=True)
```

...you should get the behavior you want.